# how to sync a midi file with an audio file

Tags: audio, synchronization, midi

I want to take a classical music piece in .mp3 (or other audio file if necessary) file and take the same music piece in *.midi file. then - **I want to synchronize between them so as a result only the midi file would change and the timing of its beat would be synchronized with the .mp3.** So lets say - if I would play them both on the same time they would play the same notes synchronizly.

How can I do so?
(I have cubase if the answer might be there...)

Answer (score 2):

It's a tough task because general beat-tracking (follow tempo changes) hasn't yet been figured out.

There's at least one tool that does work though for matching an audio file to a midi file, assuming the audio file is almost identical to the midi file in terms of the score. But I can't remember it's named, never have used it. The place is to ask is the Music Information Retrieval community of scientists:

http://listes.ircam.fr/wws/info/music-ir

For manual mathcing, you can use modern DAW's like Logic, Pro Tools, etc, to help you with this by providing reasonably nice tools to build a detailed tempo-map of the audio file, and then the MIDI file would line right up with it, but it's a tedious task. You'll likely need tempo changes more often than every measure to get a nice alignment - it will be style-dependent.

Answer (score -1):

You could use tools that already exist. For example, if you know the tempo of the mp3, then you could use [this page](http://www.skytopia.com/software/midi/) to change the tempo on the midi file.

Comment: thanks for the tip! The thing is, that the link changes the tempo of the whole piece, and I want the tempo to change per measure - since the midi is very technical & strict in the tempo and when an orchestra plays then the tempo changes (a bit faster, a bit slower). I was wondering if there is a way to sync it per measure...